# VMWare error: VT-x is not supported on this device platform

Tags: vmware

I am installing a Linux guest on my computer. It supports VT-x, I've enabled it in the BIOS, I've turned off Hyper-V, but I haven't turned off Windows Hypervisor Platform. And, when I checked the enable VT-x for the guest, it always show an error: VT-x is not supported on this platform, continue without VT-x? Whether I clicked Yes or No, it always lead to an error. If I click Yes, it will pop up a dialog, said: VMware Workstation does not support nested virtualization on this host.

Module 'HV' power on failed.

Failed to start the virtual machine. If I click No, it will said: Failed to turn on this VM. The only thing I can do is turn off the: Virtualize VT-x for this guest, but I need VT-x turn on for this guest. Can anyone help me? Thanks! [My error][My error]
P/S: I'm a newbie to the VMWare. I don't know so much of this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my Windows 10 System with VMWare 16. It was caused by the "Container" windows feature. After switching this feature off, it worked correctly.  You can verify your settings with the ones I use. Hope that it helps you to fix the problem.

[image]